# Implementation of K-mer/n-gram in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

I want to implement k-mer/n-gram algoirthm in SQL Server. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). 
In databases, I have millions of protein sequences and I want to find k-mers as  a array.

As an example;
For `ATATAGGTCGT  | k=5` result will be

```
1 | ATATA
2 | TATAG
3 | ATAGG
4 | TAGGT
5 | AGGTC
6 | GGTCG
7 | GTCGT
```

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram  k or n is a variable. Then user function will be the best solution taking k or n as a input parameter.

```
IF object_id('dbo.nGram','IF') IS NOT NULL
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.nGram; 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.nGram(@s nvarchar(max),@ int)
RETURNS TABLE AS
  RETURN 
    WITH value AS(
       SELECT 2 p,LEFT(@s,@)g 
       WHERE LEN(@s)>=@ 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT p+1,SUBSTRING(@s,p,@)FROM value 
       WHERE LEN(@s)>p-2+@)
    SELECT g FROM value
GO
WITH t AS(
   SELECT s FROM(values('ATCGAAGGTCGT'),('AT'))t(s)
)
SELECT s,g FROM t OUTER APPLY dbo.nGram(s,2)
```

I think this query works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your volume of data, perhaps this may be more performant.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'ATATAGGTCGT')

Declare @K int =5
Declare @MaxNGram int = 10

;with cte as (
    Select Top (@MaxNGram) N = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From  master..spt_values n1
)
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select N
                      ,S=Substring(A.SomeCol,N,@K)
                 From cte
             ) B
 Where len(S)=@K
```

**Returns**

[image]